# Context menu on right click twice changes position in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the xaml code :

```
     <ContextMenu  Tag="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="{x:Static localization:Resources.SomeString}"
                                              Command="{Binding Path=Tag.RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                                             CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                                    </MenuItem>
     </ContextMenu>
```

The above code on first right click opens the context menu at cursor position. On second right click places the context menu on top left of screen. Why does this happen ? How do i fix this

Tried setting Placement="MousePoint" in ContextMenu. Still the issue exist